# var List<struct> Unknown type C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have this code:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     struct Address
     {
        public string sIPAddress;
        public int nPort;
        public int nErrors; // number of errors
        public int nConnections; // num succesful connections
     }

    var listAddresses = new List<Address>();
    public LoadList()
    {
         String str;
         str=listAddresses.Count().ToString(); // C# Unknown type of member listAddresses
    }
}
```

And I get this error C# Unknown type of member in the strListAddresses.Count line

Comment: Count is a property not a method.  Just remove the parens after Count.

Comment: @JeffPrince That's not what's causing the issue. Besides, there is an [extension method `Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx) for all implementations of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: `Count()` is an extension of `IEnumerable<>`, so it's fine.  Not really the problem though.

Comment: It's not the count the problem, I cannot access any member of List

Comment: It is not allowed  to use var when declaring class member.
You should use  `new List<Address>() listAddresses = new List<Address>();` instead.

Comment: OK, so to answer your question more fully:  (1) the var for listAddresses needs to be a List<Address> instead (you can't use a var at that scope level; (2) the function LoadList() needs to have a return type; and (3) you can either change the Count() to a property or add a using for System.Linq in which case you can leave Count();

Comment: Thanks! with List<Address> works.